# Discord.js Interaction await messages cannot get message objects

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Once a user creates an interaction in a discord channel I want to listen for new incoming messages in that channel. Here is the code I got

```js
if (interaction.customId.startsWith('TRIGGER')) {
  let filter = (m) => m.author.id === interaction.author.id;
  interaction.channel
    .send(`Are you sure to delete all data? \`YES\` / \`NO\``)
    .then(() => {
      interaction.channel
        .awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 30000,
          errors: ['time'],
        })
        .then((message) => {
          message = message.first();
          if (
            message.content.toUpperCase() == 'YES' ||
            message.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y'
          ) {
            message.channel.send(`Deleted`);
          } else if (
            message.content.toUpperCase() == 'NO' ||
            message.content.toUpperCase() == 'N'
          ) {
            message.channel.send(`Terminated`);
          } else {
            message.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`);
          }
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
          interaction.channel.send('Timeout');
        });
    });
}
```

However I don't get the message objects. Its like no messages are send

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue most likely lies in your filter as no interaction has an `author` property. Consider changing your filter to the following:

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === interaction.user.id;
```